# Can two requests be made in one sentence using ください?

Tags: て-form

For example,

> 許して正してください

Or does this make little sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can join two or more verbs using the te-form and say ください only once.

> - 帰って寝てください。 Please go home and have a sleep.
> - 食べて飲んで楽しんでください。 Eat, drink and have fun!

However, your example 許して正してください makes little sense to me, although it's grammatically correct. What is this sentence supposed to mean? "Please forgive and amend"?

**EDIT:** 許して正してください makes little sense mainly because 正す lacks an object, and 許す and 正す do not share the same object (i.e. you want to say "forgive *me*" and "correct *my Japanese sentences*"). Using the te-form implies the two verbs are performed either in succession or at the same time, as one set. "Forgive-and-correct" is not one set action. In this case it's better to split the sentence into two: "間違っても許してください。間違いがあれば直してください。"

Comment: Ah I forgot, the context was 「私の日本語が実践している。でも、先生がないから簡単な日本語しか分からない。許して正してください。」 As to whether the rest is grammatically correct I'm unsure. So it was supposed to mean 'Please excuse and correct [my poor language].'

Comment: @Noktis Please see my edit. And probably you want to use 練習 instead of 実践. See any dictionary for the difference.